# how to map sharepoint mapped resource folder to app_globalResources folder  in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

how to map sharepoint mapped resource folder to app_globalResources folder ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply mark your resource file as 'AppGlobalResource' for the DeploymentType property. See my earlier answer here for more detail:

[Has the deployment of resource files and site maps been improved in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/has-the-deployment-of-resource-files-and-site-maps-been-improved-in-sharepoint-20/2551#2551)